# What do the symbols on the Fatigue gauge mean?

Tags: the-long-dark

In The Long Dark, pressing <kbd>F</kbd> (on PC) brings up the status page:

[image: status page]

This includes the Fatigue gauge:

[image: fatigue gauge close-up]

Sometimes there's a yellow exclamation mark on top of it, and sometimes part of the meter is red - what do these indicate?

Comment: if you stop starving, does it go away?

Answer (score 6):

It seems the exclamation mark appears if you have been starving for a long amount of time. It means your stamina will drop faster than normal.

The red part of the meter represents a reduced maximum, it has the same cause but appears later and slowly grows.

Eating doesn't immediately fix this. Eating and then sleeping cures it.